# How to add hours to current time in python

Tags: python, time, addition, timedelta

I am able to get the current time as below:

```
from datetime import datetime
str(datetime.now())[11:19]
```

***Result***

```
'19:43:20'
```

Now, I am trying to add `9 hours` to the above time, how can I add hours to current time in Python?

Comment: To get the current time formatted that way, have a look at `datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 529):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

nine_hours_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9)
#datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 23, 24, 31, 774118)
```

And then use string formatting to get the relevant pieces:

```
>>> '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(nine_hours_from_now)
'23:24:31'
```

If you're only formatting the datetime then you can use:

```
>>> format(nine_hours_from_now, '%H:%M:%S')
'23:24:31'
```

Or, as @eumiro has pointed out in comments - `strftime`

Comment: Why isn't this the Best Answer? Is there any side effects? unreported bug?

Comment: @Braza the OP just hasn't chosen to accept it. No side effects or bugs.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for your reply :). I tested it and I confirm.

Comment: This isn't DST-safe though.

Comment: The question asks how to **add** hours, but **subtracting** hours could be done in two ways: 1) Use the subtraction operator (`-`) instead of addition operator (`+`); according to the documentation "`timedelta` objects support certain additions and subtractions with date and `datetime` objects "  2) Pass a negative value to any of the `timedelta` parameters; according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), "Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative."

Comment: Its not working with python2.7. Whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 48):

Import [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> str(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9))[11:19]
'01:41:44'
```

But the better way is:

```
>>> (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'01:42:05'
```

You can refer [`strptime` and `strftime` behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to better understand how python processes dates and time field

Comment: The links to python docs give insights into **parsing and formatting date/time**.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer which is significant for nowadays (python 3.9 or later).

Use strptime to create a datetime object from the timestring. Add 9 hours with timedelta, and match the time format with the timestring you have.

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

    time_format = "%H:%M:%S"

    timestring = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9))[11:19], time_format)

    #You can then apply custom time formatting as well as a timezone.

    TIMEZONE = [Add a timezone] #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

    custom_time_format = "%H:%M"

    time_modification = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestring.timestamp(), ZoneInfo(TIMEZONE)).__format__(custom_time_format)
```

While I think it's more meaningful to apply a timezone, you don't necessarily need to, so you can also simply do that:

```
time_format = "%H:%M:%S"

timestring = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9))[11:19], time_format)

time_modification = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestring.timestamp())
```

> datetime

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

> strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

> timedelta

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

> zoneinfo

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo

Answer (score 3):

This works for me working with `seconds` not hours and also using a function to convert back to UTC time.

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta 
import datetime


def utc_converter(dt):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    utc_timestamp = utc_time.timestamp()
    return utc_timestamp



# create start and end timestamps
_now = datetime.datetime.now()
str_start = str(utc_converter(_now))
_end = _now + timedelta(seconds=10)
str_end = str(utc_converter(_end))
```

Comment: `utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` is unnecessary - tzinfo of `dt` will already be set correctly to timezone.utc Also, you should either import the module or specific classes form it, not both.

Comment: Any chance you could give me a tip on what that looks like through posting an answer with reference to my answer? I could use this, any help appreciated not a lot of wisdom here.

Comment: you mean the imports or tzinfo? Regarding imports, in the first line of your code snippet, you import specific classes from the module, in the second line, you *also* import the whole module (which of course includes the classes). Both methods are ok, just use only one of them to improve readability ;-)