# Python - How would I go about adding days to the current day on the system and then display what date that will be?

Tags: python, date, calendar

This is basically an algorithm:

1. Load the date which is set in the system (Example: Tue Sep 24 21:44:01 2013)
2. Add 24 days to the date above
3. Print the date which we calculated in step 2.

Sorry if anyone doesn't understand, I will try to re explain if no one gets it.

Comment: Your example shows the date *and* time, not just the current day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any number of trivial searches will reveal a solution for this problem, including no small number of [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime) on this very site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add hours to current time in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python)

Answer (score 8):

Using the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
future = today + datetime.timedelta(days=24)
print future
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> future = today + datetime.timedelta(days=24)
>>> print future
2013-10-18
```

Adding the time is trivial; use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) . Sorry for not following some rules if I didn't.