# having issues with python time object

Tags: python, date, time

i am having a small program that gets time from system and dose some arithemetic on it.
here is my code:

```
import time
import datetime
c_time = time.strftime("%H:%M;%S")

# now to convert it into time object i am using 

c_time_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_time,"%H:%M;%S")

print c_time_converted
```

the output is of the form :

**1900-01-01 11:39:40**
but i want only the time part when i split and perform other operations on it i get a **string returned but i need in time format so that i can perform time arethemetic**

i want it in form **11: 39:40**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use .time():

```
from datetime import datetime
c_time = '2015-06-08 23:13:57'
c_time_converted = datetime.strptime(c_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print c_time_converted
print c_time_converted.time()
```

prints:

```
2015-06-08 23:13:57
23:13:57
```

**EDIT (addressing a comment regarding datetime)**

Here is a simple example of using a difference in datetime:

```
from datetime import timedelta

c_time_later = '2015-06-08 23:50:21'
c_time_later_converted = datetime.strptime(c_time_later,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt = c_time_later_converted - c_time_converted
print dt  # time I was away from stackoverflow
```

prints: `0:36:24`

now we will add `dt` time back to `c_time` above and see that we recover `c_time_later`:

```
print (c_time_converted + dt).time()
```

prints: `23:50:21`

Or add an hour using timedelta:

```
print (c_time_converted + timedelta(hours=1)).time() # prints 00:13:57
```

Comment: This works great but when i use 
datetime.strptime( someTime,"%H:%M:%S").time() + datetime.strptime( someOtherTime,"%H:%M:%S").time()

it gives error

Comment: You can add `datetime.timedelta` objects to the datetimeobject. And then switch to `.time()` when you want to print.

Comment: @user3521918 Right, as camz points out, only add a datetime.timedelta to a datetime.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor change in your code. Please check. it will give you time only.

```
import time
import datetime
c_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# now to convert it into time object i am using 
c_time_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_time,"%H:%M:%S")
print c_time_converted.time()
```

Comment: but after using .time() arithemetic of two such values is not supported but that  is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: I am totally agree with @Scott. You can use time timedelta object add two times and next get the time form the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
import time
import datetime
c_time = time.strftime("%H:%M;%S")

c_time_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_time,"%H:%M;%S")

print c_time_converted.time()
```

Output :

```
12:04:31
```

Get Current Date and Time.

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
2015-06-09 12:09:09
```