# Python Programming: add years to current time

Tags: python

How do I display 5 years and 5 days later to from my current time 
Example :

```
Year : 2017 
newYear: 2022
```

How to do it? 
My current time format looks like this :

```
import datetime
X=datetime.datetime.now()
print ("year：%s" %x.year)
```

Comment: You can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python/13685221#13685221) to use `timedelta(years=5, days=5)` ...

Comment: @JonClements `class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)` from the docs  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta. there seems to be no years argument. I think you're wrong.

Comment: @s_vishnu ooops - confusing that with dateutil's relativedelta...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add one year in current date PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741618/add-one-year-in-current-date-python)

Comment: You're talking about days, but all you show is years… so `datetime.now().year + 5`…?!

Comment: @deceze `datetime(2016, 2, 29).replace(year=2021)`...

Comment: @Jon The point is about if OP is only interested in the year itself.

Comment: @deceze sure... simple in that case.. but the *and 5 days later* not so much.

Answer (score 4):

It's simplest to use the 3rd party `dateutil` and `relativedelta` here which conveniently takes `years` as a delta option and will handle leap years for you, eg:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dt = datetime.now() + relativedelta(years=5, days=5)
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 4, 13, 49, 33, 650299)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use [`arrow`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest):

```
>>> import arrow
>>> ar = arrow.utcnow()
>>> ar.shift(years=5, days=5)
<Arrow [2022-09-04T12:50:26.609842+00:00]>
```

Comment: Always forget about arrow and it's quite nice that you can do `arrow.utcnow().shift(years=5, days=5)` directly...

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps:

```
from calendar import isleap
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
X=datetime.now()

day_count = sum(365 + isleap(yr) for yr in range(X.year + 1, X.year + 6)) + 5

Y = X + timedelta(days=day_count)
```

Note: `timedelta` does not accepts `years` directly, you have to do it using `days`. It is not the best method but can be done this way.

Comment: Never heard of leap years ?

Comment: You might also want to check your logic... This gives you 2022-07-22...

Comment: If you're going to do it this way - make it way less complicated (and correct) and use `day_count = sum(365 + isleap(yr) for yr in range(X.year + 1, X.year + 6)) + 5`

Comment: @Eduardo you're welcome - you only need the +5 in one place though.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, I overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my Late reply, I have been extremely busy these past few days.
My code will first of all add 5 years to the current year, then add five days, making sure to change it if It goes over the maximum allowed. (Which is 31 for August) But you can expand it for the other months too. This is just the concept.

```
    import datetime
X=datetime.datetime.now()
print ("year：%s" %X.year)
newY = X.year + 5
print("new year: %s" %newY)
newD = X.day + 5
if X.month == 1 or X.month == 3  or X.month == 5 or X.month == 7 or X.month == 8 or X.month == 10 or X.month == 11 or X.month == 12:
    # Test if the Month has 31 days
    if X.day + 5 > 31:
        op1 = X.day + 5
        op2 = op1 - 31
        new = X.month + 1
        print("month: {}".format(new))

newXD = None
```