# How can i add 7 hours into api_time?

Tags: python, datetime

```
api_time = datetime.strptime(
                    response_time, "%H:%M")
```

Debugging has shown that `api_time : 1900-01-01 06:30:00`

All i want to do is to add 7 hours so the time is 13:30:00 how can i do it

Comment: possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/q/13685201/2312051

Comment: Actually your `api_time` should be something like `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 30)` (an datetime object)

Comment: i actually want to transform that from datetime format to string, by that i mean i want 13:30 only and in string format