# Add Hours to Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How to add hours to a timestamp in python?

I have a timestamp in UTC, and I want to add hours to it. If I convert it to DateTime, it changes to local time. So, I want to add hours directly to the timestamp without converting to datetime.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input = datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=datetime.now().day)
today = datetime.now()
days = (today - input).days
d = datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day) - timedelta(seconds=time.timezone) - timedelta(days=days)
utc_midnight_timestamp = int(time.mktime(d.utctimetuple()))
```

Now I want to keep adding 1 hour to the utc_midnight_timestamp many times

```
for x in range(1,24):
   #Need to keep incrementing utc_midnight_timestamp by x hours
   #use timestamp later
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add hours to current time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python)

Comment: No, it does not. I want to add hours to the UTC timestamp. Not datetime.

Comment: But you have a datetime object?